# Для чего нужны эти 2 строки кода java?

Tags: java

```java
String a = reader.readLine();
int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116730/discussion-on-question-by-sergey-----2---java).

Answer (score 2):

Код должен выглядеть так:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String a = reader.readLine();
int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

В строке

```
String a = reader.readLine();
```

Создаем [переменную](http://proglang.su/java/variable-types) `String a` и [присваиваем](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.15.php) ей значение, которое возвращает метод `readLine()`. Этот метод возвращает строку, а присваиванием мы сохраняем эту строку в переменную `a`. Метод `readLine()` это метод [объекта класса](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.1.php) [`BufferedReader`](http://proglang.su/java/variable-types), который назвали `reader`. (Читайте про его методы по ссылке выше).

Взаимодействие с потоками ввода (В данном случае со стандартным потоком ввода или же взаимодействие с клавиатурой, если проще) реализовано в Java с помощью [класса](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.1.php)  [`InputStream`](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.7.php), объект которого мы получаем методом `in` класса [`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

В строке из комментариев

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

мы создаем объект класса BufferedReader называем его `reader` (это тоже переменная, кстати) и [инициализируем](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/609-prisvaivanie-i-inicializacija-v-java) его  [потоком ввода](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.1.php) (System.in) Обратите внимание, что создание и инициализация в коде `reader` должны быть выше, чем вызов метода `reader.readLine()`.

В этой строке

```
int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

записываем в переменную `b`типа `int` (целое число) информацию из строки `a`, предварительно преобразовывая текст, введенный с клавиатуры в целое число с помощью метода `parseInt(a)` объекта класса [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Надеюсь, что все объяснил подробно и подкрепил ссылками. На самом деле все не так сложно, как выглядит на первый взгляд. :) Прочтите теорию по ссылкам, которые не выделены серым, а затем ссылки на документацию (серенькие) и все станет проще.

Answer (score 1):

В первой строчке `String a = reader.readLine();` объект `reader` с помощью метода `read.Line()` считывает данный например из консоли (точнее сказать невозможно, так как нету кода, в котором бы было видно, как вы создали объект `reader`), считанные данные присваиваются переменной `a` типа `String` (строки). Далее (2 строка) с помощью метода `parseInt` считанная строка преобразуется в число (тип `int`) и присваивается переменной `b`. Как вы можете видеть, чтобы преобразовать строку в число, нужно передать строку (то есть переменную `а`) в метод `parseInt`.